# what is meant by stability and potential energy of molecules in cases of formation of bonds?

Tags: electrochemistry, quantum-chemistry, theoretical-chemistry, solid-state-chemistry

molecules form chemical bonds in order to gain stability. it is said that forming bonds leads to lower potential energy of molecules and makes them stable. what does stability mean?
how formation of bond leads to lower potential energy? please  explain

Answer (score -1):

The electronic energy is lowered when bonding occurs, therefore the energy levels become more stable. Stable just means they have a lower energy level.
So if we have two 1s orbitals they can combine to form a single sigma bond which has a lower energy than the components separately.
[image: Easy explanation]